# bind list of lists based on the lists location

Tags: r, purrr

I have some data similar to `mainList` below.

```
List of 2
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ col1: chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
  .. .. ..$ col2: chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ col1: chr [1:3] "3" "7" "4"
  .. .. ..$ col2: chr [1:3] "e" "d" "g"
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ col1: chr [1:3] "2" "7" "4"
  .. .. ..$ col2: chr [1:3] "l" "o" "i"
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ col1: chr [1:3] "8" "3" "4"
  .. .. ..$ col2: chr [1:3] "r" "t" "q"
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ col1: chr [1:3] "7" "5" "2"
  .. .. ..$ col2: chr [1:3] "h" "w" "p"
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ col1: chr [1:3] "9" "3" "6"
  .. .. ..$ col2: chr [1:3] "x" "y" "z"
```

I want to merge, or bind the lists based on the lists location in the list of lists.

That is, I want to merge `splt1` with `splt11`, and then merge `splt2` with `splt22` and finally `splt3` with `splt33`.

So it would take the first data frame from the first `List of 3` and merge it with the first data frame from the second `List of 3`.

This does not get what I want

```
mainList %>% 
  map(., ~bind_rows(., .id = "split"))
```

Since all of the splits are merged into a single data frame (I want them kept separate).

Data:

```
splt1 <- list(
  data.frame(
    col1 = c("1", "2", "3"),
    col2 = c("a", "b", "c")
  )
)

splt2 <- list(
  data.frame(
    col1 = c("3", "7", "4"),
    col2 = c("e", "d", "g")
  )
)

splt3 <- list(
  data.frame(
    col1 = c("2", "7", "4"),
    col2 = c("l", "o", "i")
  )
)

nestList1 <- list(
  splt1,
  splt2,
  splt3
)


splt11 <- list(
  data.frame(
    col1 = c("8", "3", "4"),
    col2 = c("r", "t", "q")
  )
)

splt22 <- list(
  data.frame(
    col1 = c("7", "5", "2"),
    col2 = c("h", "w", "p")
  )
)

splt33 <- list(
  data.frame(
    col1 = c("9", "3", "6"),
    col2 = c("x", "y", "z")
  )
)

nestList2 <- list(
  splt11,
  splt22,
  splt33
)

mainList <- list(
  nestList1,
  nestList2
)
```

EDIT:

Screenshot of the lists:

I am trying to bind together all of the `split`'s, i.e.

- `split1` will contain the results from `08001`, `08003`, `08005` ... `0801501` for each of the lists in `catalunya_madrid`.
- `split2` will contain the same results `08001`, `08003`, `08005` ... `0801501`
- and so on.

EDIT2:

```
# Function to invert the list structure
invertListStructure <-  function(ll) {
  nms <- unique(unlist(lapply(ll, function(X) names(X))))
  ll <- lapply(ll, function(X) setNames(X[nms], nms))
  ll <- apply(do.call(rbind, ll), 2, as.list)
  lapply(ll, function(X) X[!sapply(X, is.null)])
}

invertedList <- map(analysis,  ~invertListStructure(.) %>% 
                      map(.,  ~bind_rows(.x, .id = "MITMA")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `purrr::transpose()` to group list elements with the same location (i.e. the first element in list 1 with the first element in list 2 and list 3 and so on) for any number of lists. In your case, `transpose` will convert 592 lists of 216 into 216 lists of 592, each properly titled. With transpose, `l[[x]][[y]]` becomes `l[[y]][[x]]`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mainList %>% purrr::transpose() %>% 
  map(function(x) {
    flatten(x) %>% bind_rows(.id = 'id')
  })

# $splt1
#   id col1 col2
# 1  1    1    a
# 2  1    2    b
# 3  1    3    c
# 4  2    8    r
# 5  2    3    t
# 6  2    4    q
# 
# $splt2
#   id col1 col2
# 1  1    3    e
# 2  1    7    d
# 3  1    4    g
# 4  2    7    h
# 5  2    5    w
# 6  2    2    p
# 
# $splt3
#   id col1 col2
# 1  1    2    l
# 2  1    7    o
# 3  1    4    i
# 4  2    9    x
# 5  2    3    y
# 6  2    6    z
```

Note that you only need to `flatten` if the data.frame is in a list of length 1, by itself. If you have a list of data.frames (as opposed to a list of lists, each of which contains one data.frame, as in your example data), you can ignore the `flatten()` command and just bind the rows.

Your example dataset doesn't quite match your actual data, but if you make a list of two `mainList`s, it's closer. These types of operations are heavily dependent on the structure of the data, though, so I can't be sure this is what you need. All you need to do here is add a subscript.

```r
mainList2 <- list(mainList, mainList)  # First is Madrid, second is Valencia
                                       # Operations are done on Madrid only

mainList2[[1]] %>% 
  transpose() %>% 
  map(function(x) {
    flatten(x) %>% bind_rows(.id = 'id')
  })
```

If you want to do this for both elements in `mainList2`, you can wrap the whole thing in `map`.

```r
mainList2 %>% map(function(x) {
  transpose(x) %>% 
  map(function(x) {
    flatten(x) %>% bind_rows(.id = 'id')
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I did just manage to get a working solution to my problem by inverting the list (see EDIT 2 of the original post) but your `transpose` solution is much cleaner. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the pairs in following way :

```
Map(rbind, unlist(mainList[[1]], recursive = FALSE), 
           unlist(mainList[[2]], recursive = FALSE))
```

Or using `purrr` you can also add an `id` column easily.

```
library(purrr)
map2(mainList[[1]] %>% flatten, 
     mainList[[2]] %>% flatten, dplyr::bind_rows, .id = 'id')

#[[1]]
#  id col1 col2
#1  1    1    a
#2  1    2    b
#3  1    3    c
#4  2    8    r
#5  2    3    t
#6  2    4    q

#[[2]]
#  id col1 col2
#1  1    3    e
#2  1    7    d
#3  1    4    g
#4  2    7    h
#5  2    5    w
#6  2    2    p

#[[3]]
#  id col1 col2
#1  1    2    l
#2  1    7    o
#3  1    4    i
#4  2    9    x
#5  2    3    y
#6  2    6    z
```

Comment: Thanks. This gives me an error: `Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 126531
* `.y` has length 154336`. I have added an edit with a screenshot of my lists.